# Complex Integral and Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I need help solving the following textbook problem (translated):

> Suppose $z_1,z_2,...,z_n$ (where $n\geq2$) are complex numbers. Show that:
> $$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_n)}dz=0$$
> for every simple closed curve $\gamma$ that encloses all $z_1,...,z_n$.

My initial idea is to use Cauchy's integral formula with partial fraction decomposition. The integrand equals
$$\frac{A}{z-z_1}+\frac{B}{z-z_2}+\frac{C}{z-z_3}...$$
and with Cauchy's integral formula the integral evaluates to
$$2\pi(A+B+C...).$$

I find it hard to show that $A+B+C...$ would be $0$. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: To show that $A+B+...=0$, multiply your fraction by $z$ and let $z\to \infty$ (and use $n\ge 2$)

Comment: @Kelenner Sorry I don't really understand how that would show the sum is equal to 0.

Comment: What is the limit of $z/[(z-z_1)(z-z_2)....]$ as $z \to \infty $ ?

Comment: 0, I suppose, but your multiplying only the numerator, or am I missing something?

Comment: OK Put $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_n)}=\frac{A}{z-z_1}+\frac{B}{z-z_2}+\frac{C}{z-z_3}...$. Mulltiply $f(z)$ by $z$. For the second term, the limit if $z\to \infty$ is $A+B+..$. For the first term, it is $0$.

Comment: Got it, but am I allowed to let $z$ approach infinity, since $z$ is a complex number. Is it not more correct to let $|z|$ approach infinity?

Comment: If you have problem with $z$  complex, you can simply take $z$ real, and let $z\to +\infty$...